# Failed in installing salt-stack minion(AWS Linux env)

Tags: linux, salt-stack

My steps:

```
# cd /usr/local/src/ 
# wget http://mirrors.sohu.com/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

# wget http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
# rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

# yum install python-jinja2

#yum -y install salt-minion --enablerepo=epel-testing
```

THEN:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: salt-2015.5.9-4.el6.noarch (epel-testing)
           Requires: python-msgpack
Error: Package: salt-2015.5.9-4.el6.noarch (epel-testing)
           Requires: python-zmq
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I think I already installed the missing two:

```
[root@xxx src]# pip install pyzmq  --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
[root@xxx src]# pip install msgpack-python 
Requirement already up-to-date: msgpack-python in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

Still cannot work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question but anyway. rpm package and pip package are not the same. Even if you have it installed in pip, it doesn't mean corresponding rpm is actually installed. It still misses these rpm packages.